# FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException - Tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat, grails, server

The application is running fine in localhost:8080 however when I make war and deploy the war in tomcat manager after that the project doesn't start and gets these errors. Grails 4.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6dQK.png)

Error from Catalina.out

```
28-Dec-2021 19:50:15.068 INFO [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-200] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2021-12-28 19:50:18.155 ERROR --- [1-8009-exec-200] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Set org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.findAll(java.util.Set, groovy.lang.Closure)'
    at org.grails.config.NavigableMapPropertySource.<init>(NavigableMapPropertySource.groovy:38)
    at org.grails.config.yaml.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:85)
    at org.grails.config.yaml.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadDocuments(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadForFileExtension(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:474)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:444)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$null$6(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:426)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$7(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:426)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:423)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:203)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:187)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:177)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1415)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:223)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:666)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I added `groovy:groovy-all` dependency in `build.gradle`

Example:

```
implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.6'
```

It worked for me